# Uber API Unauthorized access issue

Tags: java, uber-api

I am currently working on integrating Uber rest api with my Alexa skill.

I am not able to make a ride request using the Uber API. I am using the sandbox version of the API:

```
 https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests
```

When I invoke the above API, I am getting:

> "401 Unauthorized" as the response.

I am using Java 8 for development .

I am using the access token from the Uber developer dashboard. Under the "SETTINGS" tab, in the "TEST WITH A PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN" section, there is a "GENERATE NEW ACCESS TOKEN" button. Clicking on this button generates the access token.

I am setting the access token generated above in the Authorization header. Here is the code snippet:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
```

Do I need to set anything under the "AUTHORIZATIONS" tab in the Uber developer dashboard? Currently I have not made any changes and left everything default.

Do I need to encode the access token before setting it in the header?

Please let me know.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the dashboard-generated token for the "Limited Access" scopes (such as `requests` needed for `POST v1/requests`), you will have to go through the OAuth Steps to generate an access token to test with in Sandbox.

Since you cannot use the dashboard token to test out the `POST v1/requests` endpoint in sandbox, try this for a quick way to generate a token to test with:

1. Go to this URL in your browser (replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your application client ID and YOUR_CALLBACK_URL with your callback URL - set the callback URL in the Authorizations tab in Dashboard - could be `localhost`):

   ```
   https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id= YOUR_CLIENT_ID&scope=request&redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL
   ```
2. Sign in with your uber developer account and click "Allow"
3. You will be redirected to your `redirect_uri` with a `code` query string, copy the value of `code` and paste it in this cURL command to get your access token (replace all other values needed as well):

   ```
   curl -F 'client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' \
       -F 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
       -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
       -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI' \
       -F 'code=CODE_FROM_REDIRECT' \
       https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
   ```

If it's successful, you should get an `access_token` in the response.

More information in [the Authorization guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/authentication/introduction#oauth-20)

You also do not have to encode the access token before setting it in the header.

I hope that helps!

Comment: In step one we have to do manually copy url and put in browser and get code  and code expired in 10 min so every time . but how to get code through api call ?.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Or copy url is one time job ?

Comment: The nature of OAuth 2.0 authorization grant flow is you have to ask the user to authenticate with your app for the first time (step 1). Then, when you exchange the `code` for the `access_token` (step 3), you need to save this `access_token` somewhere and use it for further requests to the API. The access token will include a `refresh_token` in the payload, so you can refresh the access token when it expires after 30 days.